# How can I upload sketches to an Arduino over a raspberry pi?

Tags: arduino, linux

I am doing robotics project on Raspberry pi and Arduino. The Arduino UNO is connected to raspberry pi. I am using the raspberry pi in Putty (SSH) now.

I want to setup user interface for raspberry pi also most importantly i want to use Arduino IDE to work and load Arduino sketch into system. How to do this?

Comment: As you are probably running Linux on the Rasp Pi, the best approach would be to find out how can you upload sketches from linux. I believe there are many Linux user Arduino enthusaists. To start with: http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Raspbian

Comment: As per [my comment here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/54474/5538) the Arduino IDE is available in Raspbian and therefore so should be `avrdude`, which I believe is the (command line) tool used for uploading sketches to actual Atmel based devices like the Arduino (the IDE can be used for other things as well).  I haven't tried though, so won't post that as answer.  If you follow this lead and it works, please add an answer of your own.  I don't know about *remote* use of the IDE, but you should be able to compile a sketch, transfer it, then use `avrdude`.

Answer (score 1):

You could install ser2net on the RPi and configure a programmer in /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/programmers.txt that communicates over the network.